# Sum values by group in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a number of `Case` objects that have been parsed from a .csv file that each contain a `brokerName`, `id` and `value`

I have a `List<Case>` populated by case objects, and I need to return the total value of all of the cases combined, grouped by the brokerName.

So if the following data exists

```
Case1: "Bob", 1, 200
Case2: "Bob", 2, 300
Case3: "Roger", 3, 100
Case4: "Keith", 4, 50
Case5: "Keith", 5, 300
```

Then the returned values would be

```
Bob: 500
Roger: 100
Keith: 350
```

I want to be able to do this in Linq, but I can't figure out how to get the result that I need. I'm not sure how to group by and then sum the values.

I feel like an anonymous object will need to be used to do this, and by creating an anonymous object I can keep track of a running total for each broker. But I can't get to the answer.

So far I've got

```
var query = from c in CaseList
            group c by c.Broker
            select new
            {
                //?
            };

foreach(var c in query)
{
    decimal total = c.CaseValue;
}
```

But I'm not sure where to go from here

Answer (score 2):

After group by `Broker`, you can create anonymous instance in `Select` by `new` keyword

```
var groups = list.GroupBy(x=> x.Broker)
                 .Select(g => new { BrokerName = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(c => c.value) });
foreach(var g in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{g.BrokerName} : {g.Sum}")
}
```

it shows the output likes :

```
Bob: 500
Roger: 100
Keith: 350
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an overload of GroupBy to transform the results of the grouping into your required format:

```
var groups = list.GroupBy(x=> x.Broker, (broker,cases) => new { BrokerName = broker, Sum = cases.Sum(c=>c.value) });
foreach(var g in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{g.BrokerName} : {g.Sum}")
}
```